# How to convert Java function to postgresql function

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql

I have oracle function which I want to convert into PostgreSQL below I am mentioning the oracle function.

```
create or replace
FUNCTION             "BOMQTYON" (M_Product_ID NUMBER, M_Warehouse_ID NUMBER,
        M_Locator_ID NUMBER, LocatorType VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER
    AS LANGUAGE JAVA
    NAME 'org.compare.sqlj.Product.bomQtyOnHold(int,int,int,java.lang.String) return java.math.BigDecimal';
```

I tried to create a  function in PostgreSQL but it given me error on language JAVA does not exists

Comment: Please post what you tried so far and the problems you are having

Answer (score 1):

You will have to rewrite your function in one of the server programming languages on PostgreSQL.

Apart from the usual suspects PL/pgSQL and PL/Perl, you could consider using [PL/Java](https://tada.github.io/pljava/), but you'll have to build it yourself, and don't expect that you can just reuse your Oracle code without modifications.

Comment: I tried to create  PL java language but it s not showing in drop down list please suggest me how can i create PL/java

Comment: I have no idea what drop-down list you are talking about. What program has this drop-down list? About installation: did you follow [the instructions](https://tada.github.io/pljava/install/install.html)? With what success?